# Why are Closed questions still visible on the newest tab?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, tabs

Why are [Closed] questions still visible on the newest tab? And are they filtered off in the "new" way of doing the newest tab like SO is set up?

It would be nice to have them filtered off so we don't have to scroll through them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They're presumably there because questions can be closed quickly and it gives other, 3K+ rep users the opportunity to notice the questions and vote to reopen them.  It also gives the editors an opportunity to identify that a question might need some editorial assistance, in order to get it reopened.

Whilst it might be nice to have the option to filter out closed posts, I don't think it should be the default behaviour.