# Site email says closed questions are not visible to the public: wrong

Tags: bug, closed-questions, email, wording

The website documentation has been corrected, but this email form letter
is still inaccurate

> `From: Stack Overflow <do-not-reply@stackoverflow.email>`
> `Subject: Your question has been closed`
>
> ... What should I do next? ...
>
> - Submit your edits. Edits will be reviewed by trusted community
>   members. If approved, the question will **become visible to the public.**

That is not technically correct. Closed questions are still visible to the public. Deleted questions are not.

It would be better if it said:

"If approved, the **revised** question will become visible to the public."

See also:

- [Wrong instructions in email about duplicate question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374723/wrong-instructions-in-email-about-duplicate-question)
- [Are questions that are closed visible to visitors from search engines?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163910/are-questions-that-are-closed-visible-to-visitors-from-search-engines)
- [Why are Closed questions still visible on the newest tab?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89776/why-are-closed-questions-still-visible-on-the-newest-tab)

I am just saying: please correct the wording in the email.

Comment: It’s probably referring to the fact that the question is bumped to the front page when it is edited.